# Symfony form validation vs validator service

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I'm having a strange issue and I think I'm missing something.

I'm using Symfony 2.7 and I'm working on a user password update function.

I have a user entity (Extends FosUserBundle user entity) with multiple properties. One of them is the plainPassword (ofcourse not persisted to DB).

**User.php**

```
...

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="prefix_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
 *
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="unique", groups={"registration"})
 * @UniqueEntity("username", message="unique", groups={"registration"})
 *
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

...

    /* @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="blank",groups={"accountUpdate", "passwordUpdate"})
     * @Assert\Length(min=8, minMessage="short", max=4096, maxMessage="long")
     */
    protected $plainPassword;
```

As you can see I'm using annotations for the validation of my properties. I'm also using validation groups to be sure only the correct properties will be validated.

I have created a form

**UserUpdatePasswordType.php**

```
class UserUpdatePasswordType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => 'password_mismatch',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'intention' => 'resetting',
            /**
             * Need to add method to prevent this form from bein marked as invalid.
             * @see http://sroze.io/2013/10/30/symfony2-form-patch-requests-and-handlerequest-form-never-valid/
             */
            'method' => 'PATCH'
        ));
    }
```

I'm building a restful API with FOSRestBundle and I'd like to provide a nice and clean output if form validation fails.

As far as I know I can validate a form in two ways:

1. $formErrors = $this->get('validator')->validate($user, null, ['passwordUpdate']);
2. $form->isValid() and to get errors $form->getErrors()

Now the strange part comes, the two methods above give different validation errors.

**Request parameters**

```
user_update_password[plainPassword][first]:sffsdfdsfds
user_update_password[plainPassword][second]:fdsfdsfsd
```

**Response from $formErrors = $this->get('validator')->validate($user, null, ['passwordUpdate']);**
The response is not correct, because the plainPassword is not blank.

```
{
      "property_path": "plainPassword",
      "message": "blank"
}
```

**Response form $form->isValid() which seems to look better**

```
"form": {
      "children": {
        "plainPassword": {
          "children": {
            "first": {
              "errors": [
                "password_mismatch"
              ]
            },
            "second": {}
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "errors": []
```

The only difference I can see is the difference that I'm not providing a validation group name in the $form->isValid().

Why am I getting different results and what should I do to fix?
Can I provide a validation group name to the $form->isValid() or should I fix a problem with the $validator->validate code?

I would love to see how this is managed in other Symfony2 based APIs...

Comment: May I ask why you are repeating a functionality of FOS User Bundle in a first place? There is a plainPassword field in a BaseUser, and validation constraints are quite easy to edit.

Comment: @DmitryMalyshenko Thanks for asking, but I'm using this as an example for the problem I'm facing.. In my app I'm not repeating any FOSUser code.

Answer (score 7):

There're three reasons of difference.

1. You probably don't set data from `request` to `model` when validating by service. Use `$form->submit($request)` as a safe proxy data setter
2. You don't use validation groups in form (do it in `setDefaults`) BTW. Your `@Assert\Length` won't be used until you add groups to this annotation or add validation group `Default` to `service/form` validators array
3. You used `repeated` type in form, which have additional `Constraints` in comparison to your model `Constraints`. Form validator checks for both model and form constraints belonging to passed validation groups (by default 'Default' group is used)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is another difference (besides using of validation group).
When you are using Form (rather than just a Validator), there is a ['repeated'](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html) type involved.

> Validation
>
> One of the key features of the repeated field is internal
>   validation (you don't need to do anything to set this up) that forces
>   the two fields to have a matching value. If the two fields don't
>   match, an error will be shown to the user.

So actually in one case you're using an additional constraint, and at another you are not. No surprise validations give different results.

So in your case I would probably make own implementation of "repeat" for  a password in the User object and would use a validator service.

Another option that I see is to use a Form object to validate User, but it's not a clean and clear way to make API.

Comment: Why using forms in not clean way in API? API is just request with different response than HTML. You can return form errors in JSON or XML. moreover there is no good reason to abandon form transformers and subscribers just because you build API.

Comment: Because the chapter about Forms on symfony's documentation starts from "Dealing with HTML forms is one of the most common...". This component in it's core is designed for HTML, and I think it's not right to use it when one doesn't use HTML

Comment: No, it isn't. Only part responsible for HTML is `$form->createView()` and it's not obligatory. Using data straight `from` request in big security issue, form normalize data and prevent most of security issues.

Answer (score -2):

The big difference is that one validator is validating the model and the other is validating the form data. The model requires the field to not be empty.  The [FOSUser bundle ChangePasswordFormType](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/ChangePasswordFormType.php) adds the [UserPassword constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UserPassword.html) to the form for validation.  The UserPassword validator checks that the form values were properly submitted.

If you are using www-form-urlencoded data in your API, use the form validator.  It will give more precise errors as they will be related to the state of the data submitted not the state of the data after it was transformed into the model.

Comment: Both validate model, form also provide additional constraints